# Why do we not allow the empty set as a filter?

Tags: soft-question, filters

The definition of a filter requires that it be nonempty. But the empty set does satisfy the other two conditions. So, why do we not allow the empty set as a filter? Wouldn't it be more useful, because then the set of filters of a set would have a bottom element?

Comment: The set of filters on a set $X$ already has a bottom element, namely $\{X\}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Okay, fair point, but why do we not allow the empty set as a filter?

Comment: In a compact space, every filter has a cluster point. But not the "empty filter". In general, if you want to answer questions of the form "Why is this definition like this?" you have to look at what it is used for.

Comment: @RobertFurber You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @user107952 Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when asking why a definition is the way it is, it is best to look at what the definition is intended to be used for.

Filters are used to provide a notion of convergence suitable for general topological spaces (as well as being part of a definition of continuity at a single point). Let's use $X$ to refer to an arbitrary topological space.

Recall that a filter $\mathcal{F}'$ is *finer* than a filter $\mathcal{F}$ iff $\mathcal{F}' \supseteq \mathcal{F}$. A filter *converges* to a point $x \in X$ if it is finer than the neighbourhood filter of $x$. Since the neighbourhood filter of a point always contains the whole space $X$, the "empty filter" can never converge to anything.

A *cluster point* $x$ of a filter $\mathcal{F}$ is a point such that every set $S \in \mathcal{F}$, $x$ is in the closure of $S$. The "empty filter" has no cluster point. This spoils two things. First, $X$ is compact iff every filter has a cluster point - this would have to be rephrased to say "except the 'empty filter'".

Secondly, $x$ is a cluster point of a filter $\mathcal{F}$ iff there is a filter $\mathcal{F}'$ finer than $\mathcal{F}$ converging to $x$ - this would have to be rephrased with an exception as well, because every filter is finer than the "empty filter", which has no cluster point.